# Dependency injection into abstract class typescript(Angular2)

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, abstract-class

I have abstract class(without constructor) and I want to inject another class into it.

Abstract class:

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '../../shared/services/errorHandler.service';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';


export abstract class BaseApiComponent<T> {
    @Inject(ErrorHandler) errorHandler: ErrorHandler;

    this.errorHandler.test();
}
```

Injected class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandler  {
  constructor() { }


  public test() {
    console.log('Test');
  }

}
```

And I have next error

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

How i can fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of Angular 2 RC5 the DI becomes simpler. You don't need to decorate the stuff with `@Injectable()`. Instead, you just declare it for DI in one place - NgModule.

```ts
export class ErrorHandler {
    test() {
        console.log('ErrorHandler.test()');
    }
}

export abstract class BaseApiComponent<T> {
    // use protected property parameter in abstract class
    // for accessibility from descendants.
    constructor(protected errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {}

    someMethod() {
        this.errorHandler.test();
    }
}

export class ApiComponentImpl<T> extends BaseApiComponent<T> {
    // use @Inject decorator
    constructor(@Inject(ErrorHandler) errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {
        super(errorHandler);
    }
}
```

*app.module.ts*:

```
// class declarations
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        ErrorHandler,
        ApiComponentImpl
    ]
})
export class AppModule{
}

// bootstrap the app
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

You can employ OpaqueToken to improve modularity and remove type dependency:

```
export const errorHandlerToken = new OpaqueToken('ErrorHandler');
```

in the module:

```
    providers: [
        // using OpaqueTokens you can change the provided value
        // to anything without changing consumer code 
        {provide: errorHandlerToken, useClass: ErrorHandler},
```

constructor:

```
    constructor(@Inject(errorHandlerToken) errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {
```

Answer (score 17):

Angular DI only supports constructor injection, which means you need a constructor.

You also can't inject into an abstract class directly because an abstract class is not supposed to be instantiatable.

Therefore it has to be like:

```
export abstract class BaseApiComponent<T> {
    constructor(errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {}

    someMethod() {
     this.errorHandler.test();
    }
}

export class ApiComponentImpl<T> {
    constructor(errorHandler: ErrorHandler) {
      super(errorHandler);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see why. I don't know TS too well but usually abstract classes can have concrete implementations (properties, methods) and they need to be initialized.

Comment: It make sense. But just tried to inject an abstract service class because I wanted to show my colleague that you can't do that. The is class decorated with @injecatble and provided in root and it seems like it works. Do you know why? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nbpvtg?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Interesting catch. Seems Angular doesn't generate `new Lala(...)` code but creates the instance by some other way there the compiler can't catch that an abstract class is instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an angular developer, but looking at the examples the `@Inject` decorator is always used as a [parameter decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators) and not as a [property decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators).

As the two decorator types are different, that might cause the problem but I'm not sure.
Try:

```
export abstract class BaseApiComponent<T> {
    private errorHandler: ErrorHandler;

    protected constructor(@Inject(ErrorHandler) handler) {
        this.errorHandler = handler;
    }

    public error() {
        this.errorHandler.test();
    }
}
```

Also I'm not sure when you're actually using `this.errorHandler.test();` as it can't just sit there in the class, I moved it into the `error` method.

---

#### edit

Right. You'll need to inject in the extending class and then pass the instance to the parent:

```
export abstract class BaseApiComponent<T> {
    protected errorHandler: ErrorHandler;

    protected constructor(handler: ErrorHandler) {
        this.errorHandler = handler;
    }
}

export class Restaurants extends BaseApiComponent<any> {
    constructor(@Inject(ErrorHandler) handler) {
        super(handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am inheriting from BaseApiComponent
export class Restaurants extends BaseApiComponent<any> {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    super();
  }

And i  have error with this constructor : "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"

Maybe I can inject it without constructor?

Comment: Oh. Now I see what you mean. Try my revised answer

Answer (score 0):

You can declare service you need as private or protected member of target abstract class and then use [inject](https://angular.io/api/core/inject) function in its constructor:

```js
import { inject } from '@angular/core';

export abstract class BaseApiComponent<T> {
    
    protected errorHandler: ErrorHandler;

    constructor() {
        this.errorHandler = inject(ErrorHandler);
    }

    testService() {
        this.errorHandler.test();
    }
}
```

And you can use it in the implementations of this abstract class:

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponentImplementation extends BaseApiComponent<T> {
    override testService() {
        super.testService();
        this.errorHandler.test();
    }
}
```

This solution is an approach to inject dependencies to abstract classes without touching their implementations.